# How do I filter and display the contents of my table in my django template according to date

Tags: django

I have a template that displays users data (date, name, address, contact no) in a tabular format. How do I apply a filter button on this template that takes in the users date and modifies the table to show the entries for that particular date.

**Table.html**

```
 {% block content %}
<h1 style="font-size:300%;">ATTENDANCE TABLE</h1><hr /><br />

<table>
<tr>
    <th>DATE</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>SITE</th>
    <th>TYPE OF LEAVE</th>
    <th>REASON</th>
    <th>ARRIVAL</th>
    <th>TIME IN</th>
    <th>TIME OUT</th>
</tr>
{% for topic in topics %}
<tr> 
    <td>{{ topic.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.site }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.leave_type }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.reason }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.arrival }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.intime }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.outtime }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Once this table is displayed, I would like to have a filter button that accepts the date and modifies the table to show entries for that entered date. Would I have to create a new view or just play around with the .html file?

I tried using {{variable|date}} filter to no avail .

EDIT:
Sharing my other files to implement the form- template filter approach.

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from django.forms.fields import DateField, TimeField, DateInput, TimeInput, 

datetime
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
    from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
    from .lala import SelectTimeWidget 
    import datetime



    from .models import Topic, AppStaff

    class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    date= forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget, initial=datetime.date.today) 
    name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AppStaff.objects.values_list('agent',flat=True))
    intime=forms.TimeField(widget= SelectTimeWidget(twelve_hr=True,      required=False,use_seconds=False),required=False)
    outtime=forms.TimeField(widget= SelectTimeWidget(twelve_hr=True, required=False,use_seconds=False),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        #fields = ['site','leave_type','reason','arrival','intime','outtime']

    class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    date1= forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget, initial=datetime.date.today)
```

Views.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Topic, AppStaff 
from .forms import TopicForm, FilterForm
import datetime


def topics(request):
      """Show all topics."""
      topics = Topic.objects.all()
      context = {'topics': topics}



      return render(request, 'app/topics.html', context)



    def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_topic'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/new_topic.html', context)




    def filter(request):

        form = FilterForm()



        if request.method == "POST":
            f = FilterForm(request.POST)
            if f.is_valid():

                posts = Topic.objects.filter()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("app/filter.html",{"posts":posts})
        else:
            return render_to_response("app/filter.html",{"form":form} ,           context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

filter.html

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SITE</th>
        <th>TYPE OF LEAVE</th>
        <th>REASON</th>
        <th>ARRIVAL</th>
        <th>TIME IN</th>
        <th>TIME OUT</th>
        <th>COMMENT</th>

    </tr>
    {% for post in posts %}

        <tr>
            <td>{{ post.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.site }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.leave_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.reason }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.arrival }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.intime }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.outtime }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.comment }}</td>
        </tr>


  {% endfor %}




</table>
</body>
```

My FilterForm shows the date field but when I hit submit, it should open filter.html with the filtered list . Im sure I am missing something but have no idea what it really is for weeks now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templates create the page on the server side and then don't have control over what happens on the client side.

If you want to use Django templates to do the filtering you can use a form to submit the action to the server and rerender the page using template filters. However, this would be bad user experience.

I would recommend using javascript to achieve this. A good javascript lib is [datatables](https://datatables.net/). There is also a django app to for datatables [django-datatables](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable).

Full disclosure: I use the library for quite complex tables and also contributed to it.